# Profiling with TensorBoard only produces one tool (trace_viewer) out of the 5 available in the "Profile" tab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I want to profile a CNN to find out which layers are taking up more execution time.

First I import my model created in Keras and load the parameters I already trained

```
model = my_model.model_arch(parameters)    

model.load_weights(weights_path)
```

Then I enable the trace

```
logdir = 'logs' 

writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
```

Then I calculate the prediction:

```
prediction_1=model.predict(x=input,steps=steps_1)
```

And finally I write the traces:

```
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(name="model_trace", step=0, profiler_outdir='logs/trace')
```

However, I cannot see anything else than "trace_viewer" in the "profile" tab. In particular, I am interested in the "TensorFlow stats" tool (as shown in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler). I also tried a different approach with callbacks:

```
logdir = 'logs' 

model = my_model.model_arch(parameters)    

model.load_weights(weights_path)

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = '1', write_graph=True, write_images=True)

prediction_1=model.predict(x=input,steps=steps_1,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

But this one doesn't even generate a profile tab, only a "graphs" tab.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely due to using an older TensorFlow version (`< 2.2.0`). Previous versions did not have all those features.